# Is there a developed theory of arithmetic of algebraic curves of higher degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I recently became interested in applications of number theory (especially the arithmetic of points on elliptic curves) to cryptography. Just out of curiosity, is there a well-developed (books, references, papers, etc.) theory for arithmetic of higher degree curves? Are these curves particularly interesting in some context other than number theory (analysis or topology for example) and where is a good starting place to start learning?

Comment: a book by Stepanov comes to mind http://www.amazon.com/Arithmetic-Algebraic-Monographs-Contemporary-Mathematics/dp/0306110369/

Comment: In the genus 2 case there is the absurdly-titled _Prolegomena to a Middlebrow Arithmetic of Curves of Genus 2_ by Cassels and Flynn.